# objective C filling array with custom class pointers

Tags: iphone, class, arrays

```
favorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {

  [favorites addObject:[[[Favorite alloc] constructUnknown] autorelease]];



 }
```

i'm getting:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[Favorite size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x380d9c0'

why?

Favorite is my custom class, favorites an array containing 9 instances of my custom class

edit:

Favorite.h:

```
-(Favorite*)constructUnknown;
```

Favorite.m:

```
 - (Favorite*)constructUnknown{


self=[super init];

if (self) {
    image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"unknown.png"];
}

return self;

}
```

COMPLETE FAVORITES.h

```
@interface Favorite : NSObject {

NSString *identity;
bool ready;

UIImage *image;
NSURL *telephone;


}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSURL *telephone;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *identity;

//passare unknown al nome per costrutire un oggetto unknown.
-(Favorite*)constructWithID:(NSString*)name withPhoto:(UIImage*)photo andNumber:(NSString*)number;

-(Favorite*)constructUnknown;
-(NSURL*) convertToUrl:(NSString*)phone;
- (UIImage*) getImage;

@end
```

Comment: How do you define `-constructUnknown`?

Comment: i have tested the constructor on a single pointer:it works

Comment: Show us Favorite.h? I'm curious whether you've properly subclassed NSObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is likely because your `image` is not retained. Try

```
image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"unknown.png"] retain];
```

---

BTW, initializers should be named as `-initXXX` and return an `id` by convention. e.g.

```
 -(id)initWithUnknown{ ... }
```

Comment: Doesn't need to retain the `UIImage`, as the class method `imageNamed:` returns an autoreleased object, as per the ownership guidelines.

Good point on the initializer naming though.

Comment: @jshier: If the object is autoreleased, and you want to keep it around, then you *do* need to retain it.

Comment: Ah, true. My bad. Does indeed seem this would be the problem.

Comment: yeah.that works.thank you.retaining an object means it stays in memory and not be released out of his scope?

Comment: @palominoz: It's better to think in terms of ownership. `-retain` means "from now on this object is the owner of the image". Remember to `-release` it in the Favorite's `-dealloc` as it is no longer the owner of the image.

Comment: @KennyTM so it didnt work because i was calling the property "image", but the instance of the object was not the owner of the image, right?Is it correct to retain objects in properties every time a custom class is built, or is there some way useful not to retain it?

Comment: @palominoz: The instance of the object *should be* the owner, so you *should* `-retain` it.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone reads this and still doesn't reach a solution, my problem was a little different I declared the object as:

```
@class LoginViewController;

@interface LoginViewDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

}

....

@property (nonatomic, retain) AppConfiguration *CurrentAppConfig;

....

@End
```

And when I was calling it:

```
[[self.CurrentAppConfig alloc] init];
```

I was getting the same error, all I had to do was use the synthesize keyword:

```
@implementation LoginViewDelegate

....

@synthesize CurrentAppConfig;
```